# Can we deserialize InstallState file?

Tags: c#

I am trying to pass the information in Install state file to the installer class which will then uninstall.

But before passing it I need to convert the info to System.Collections.IDictionary savedState.

For this, is it possible to deserialize install state file?

[Screenshot of the Installstate file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBEGC.png)

Comment: What does the file look like? Have you written any code?

Comment: don't know how this file looks like. If it's xml or json, then yes, it's possible. There are a few examples of deserializing xml and json in c#.

Comment: it is a xml file but i am not able to deserialize it.
the start of the file looks like
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><ArrayOfKeyValueOfanyTypeanyType xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" z:Id="1" z:Type="System.Collections.Hashtable" z:Assembly="0" xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"><LoadFactor z:Id="2" z:Type="System.Single" z:Assembly="0" xmlns="">0.72</LoadFactor><Version z:Id="3" z:Type="System.Int32" z:Assembly="0" xmlns="">2</

Comment: @Sandy - probably better to [edit] your question to show a fragment (paste it in, then highlight it and hit the `{}` button so that it's shown as code). As you probably realise now, trying to put code in comments doesn't work well here.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever i've added the screenshot for the xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the [AssemblyInstaller](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.assemblyinstaller(v=vs.110).aspx) class, it *appears* (although this doesn't seem to be documented) that it will, in general, ignore any passed `savedState` parameter and will instead deal with the `INSTALLSTATE` file instead (writing it during install, reading it during uninstall).

If you're unable to use it, for some reason, you can probably use a disassembly tool to extract the necessary code from its `Uninstall` method to perform the deserialization (I believe, and it appears so, that the specific serialization methods used vary between .NET versions, so I'd recommend using the one appropriate to whichever .NET version you're currently working with).

---

This is the `Uninstall` method, decompiled from System.Configuration.Install (File Version 4.6.1590.0):

```
public override void Uninstall(IDictionary savedState)
{
    this.PrintStartText(Res.GetString("InstallActivityUninstalling"));
    if (!this.initialized)
    {
        this.InitializeFromAssembly();
    }
    string installStatePath = this.GetInstallStatePath(this.Path);
    if ((installStatePath != null) && File.Exists(installStatePath))
    {
        FileStream input = new FileStream(installStatePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings {
            CheckCharacters = false,
            CloseInput = false
        };
        XmlReader reader = null;
        if (input != null)
        {
            reader = XmlReader.Create(input, settings);
        }
        try
        {
            if (reader != null)
            {
                NetDataContractSerializer serializer = new NetDataContractSerializer();
                savedState = (Hashtable) serializer.ReadObject(reader);
            }
            goto Label_00C6;
        }
        catch
        {
            object[] args = new object[] { this.Path, installStatePath };
            base.Context.LogMessage(Res.GetString("InstallSavedStateFileCorruptedWarning", args));
            savedState = null;
            goto Label_00C6;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (reader != null)
            {
                reader.Close();
            }
            if (input != null)
            {
                input.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    savedState = null;
Label_00C6:
    base.Uninstall(savedState);
    if ((installStatePath != null) && (installStatePath.Length != 0))
    {
        try
        {
            File.Delete(installStatePath);
        }
        catch
        {
            object[] objArray2 = new object[] { installStatePath };
            throw new InvalidOperationException(Res.GetString("InstallUnableDeleteFile", objArray2));
        }
    }
}
```

You'll notice that it doesn't use whatever was passed to it as `savedSate` - by the time it uses that variable for anything (here, passing it to its base class), it's either over-written it from the `INSTALLSTATE` file or it's assigned `null` to it.

Comment: AssemblyInstaller Uninstall Method takes IDictionary savedState which can not be passed null.

Comment: @Sandy - says who? The version I'm looking at certainly doesn't raise an `ArgumentNullException` if it's passed as `null`. And, as I say, it then always overwrites any supplied value with one obtained by deserializing the `INSTALLSTATE` file or *setting* it to `null`.

Comment: With the above code i was able to deserialize InstallState file.
but when i pass this to the Uninstall method of AssemblyInstaller i am getting Object referece not set to instance exception.
Where as if i pass this state to our Dll which has the installer class it is giving 
"The savedState dictionary contains inconsistent data and might have been corrupted."
However the MSI can be uninstalled properly from Control Panel.